# How can you check whether input value is in array or not (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

```
$InputArray = @(a,e,i,o,u,1,2,3,4,5)
$UserInput = "Enter any value:"
```

How can we check that `$UserInput` is in `$InputArray` or not and prompt for correct input?

Comment: $UserInput = Read-Host "Enter any value:"
if $UserInput not match with element of $InputArray, then again ask for correct entry, which is in array.

Answer (score 73):

Use the `-contains` operator:

```
$InputArray -contains $UserInput
```

With more recent PowerShell versions (v3 and above) you could also use the `-in` operator, which feels more natural to many people:

```
$UserInput -in $InputArray
```

Beware, though, that either of them does a linear search on the reference array (`$InputArray`). It doesn't hurt if your array is small and you're not doing a lot of comparisons, but if performance is an issue using hashtable lookups would be a better approach:

```
$validInputs = @{
    'a' = $true
    'e' = $true
    'i' = $true
    'o' = $true
    'u' = $true
    '1' = $true
    '2' = $true
    '3' = $true
    '4' = $true
    '5' = $true
}

$validInputs.ContainsKey($UserInput)
```

Comment: These checks can also be inverted using `-notcontains` and `-notin`.

Answer (score 11):

I understand that you are learning but you need to use Google-fu and the documentation before coming here.

```
$inputArray -contains $userinput
```

Comment: `'a','b','c' -contains (Read-Host)`

Comment: :) Yes, didn't want to confuse a beginner.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting hack I use all the time in powershell: the `echo` command will convert unquoted arguments into a string array.

```
(echo a b c) -contains 'a'
# outputs True / returns $true
```

This is WAY EASIER than typing `@('a','b','c')`.  My fingers have never gotten fast at typing ' after every 2nd or 3rd character.